# What is the PRNG behind C++'s rand() function?

Tags: c++, random

I don't know if this question makes sense, but for example, python's random module has the Mersenne Twister 19937 as the PRNG behind it.

What would be the equivalent for C++'s random function?

edit: I know not to use the rand() function, I'm just running some test and was wondering if there was such a thing, or if it just is a LCG.

Comment: While someone will come along and actually provide an answer or a link to an answer, I'm just here to say: don't use `rand()`. Get to know and prefer the functionality available in `<random>`.

Comment: _"C++'s random function"_ - C++ has a few and [Mersenne Twister](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) is one of them. Don't use `rand()` since you don't know what you'll get on different platforms.

Comment: Use the functions in the [random](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header. Don't use `rand` - you don't know what you'll get and it can be as bad as a linear congruential generator.

Comment: C++'s equivalent of the python module you mentioned, would be using `std::mt19937`. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine

Comment: "*I know not to use the rand() function*" One of the reasons pointed out in the linked answer answers your question. Specifically, there is no answer because there is no required algorithm. Different implementations use different algorithms.

Comment: @wohlstad Appreciate your comment, but my question is the other way around, is there any specific PRNG behind that specific function?

Comment: @NicolBolas Oops I missed that, I appreciate it.

Comment: i would expect all versions of the same compiler to use the same implementation, so the  same code works the same across compiler versions. and it probably an LCG - but no guarantees

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD that's depressingly close to accurate](https://xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: Obligatory link to [`rand` Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/goingnative-2013/rand-considered-harmful)